# How to implement scrolling tabs ui using html5 + jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, tabs, scroll

I have to display 10 tabs, but i am able to show only 5 of them using jQuery in iPhone
kindly let me know can we scroll the tabs along with the tab content.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look to :

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

For scrolling. Very efficient and simple !

**Edit**

It has a lite version : https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll-lite.js